# How to select a specific sheet by name without looping

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

Is there a way to select a specific sheet in a workbook by sheet name directly rather than doing something like...

```
For Each sheet As Worksheet In workbook.Sheets
    ....
Next
```

I thought it would be as easy as typing

```
Dim sheet as Worksheet = workbook.Sheets("mySheetName")
```

Apparently it isn't that easy though...

I've also had the issue with this line...

```
Dim myWorksheets As Worksheets = myWorkbook.Worksheets
```

The above line of code says I'm doing an implicit conversion from Sheets to Worksheets. What is wrong there?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I try workbook.Sheets("sheetName") it tells me that I'm trying to convert an object to a Worksheet. Do I need to cast it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try workbook.Sheets("sheetName") it tells me that I'm trying to convert an object to a Worksheet...

If that's the error you're getting, the just do this:

```
Dim sheet as Worksheet = CType(workbook.Sheets("mySheetName"), Worksheet)
```

Comment: @user1066133, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is by activating the other worksheet and then activating/selecting the specific work sheet.

```
Windows("WorkbookName.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("SheetName").Activate
```